# How is the amount of culture granted by "Write Political Treatise" determined?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

With a Great Writer, I can "Write Political Treatise":

> This order will consume the Great Person and will grant a large amount of Culture.

Below for example I get +5472. How is this number determined?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like all the great people who produce a one-time large amount of something, it's based on your current output of that thing.  Since the writer generates culture, it will be based on how much culture you are producing.  I don't remember exactly how much it is, but it's something like 10 turns worth of your current output.  It can be a good idea to wait a few turns if you know you're about to get a culture boost!

Answer (score 0):

It's 8 turns worth of culture based on your current gain/turn on standard speed. Assuming it's standard speed, this should correspond with 684 culture per turn. If marathon, probably 228 or a third of standard.